# How do I remove part of path from the terminal

Tags: ubuntu, terminal

I give some command on terminal and then type `<Ctrl>+w` to delete the last word.

```
vim apps/up_multiplier/views/create_ads_views.py
```

If I do `<Ctrl>+w`, the path is removed and only `vim` remains.

What should I do to remove only the last fragment of path. eg: I only want to remove `create_ads_views.py` in my example.

Answer (score 4):

Try  <kbd>`<ALT>`</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd>, that should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

bind '\C-f:unix-filename-rubout'

Then ctrl+f will do the work for you.

Or, use Esc and backspace to delete words delimited by slashes.

Got answer from this page:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27927/is-it-possible-to-configure-ctrl-w-delete-word

Alternate:
Good question, what I can do is, ctrl+left, space, ctrl+e or end, ctrl+w (May be useful for long words). Looking for another good answer.

Answer (score 1):

The `bash` command lines controls are all based on Emacs.  So:

- Esc-Backspace will delete a word as Emacs defines it (as user1305989 said above)
- Ctrl-Y will put back what you deleted: so if you accidentally did Ctrl-W deleting the to the beginning of the line, then Ctrl-Y will put it back.
- Esc-b will go back a word
- Esc-f will go forward a word

I use these all the time and you get used to them.